# Сокращение домена до n-го уровня java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Допустим, у нас есть сайт https://www.reg.ru/domain/new/domeny-vtorogo-urovnya/ значит его нужно сократить до reg.ru (домена 2-го уровня)
Как это прописать в регулярном выражении, если конечно здесь с помощью них нужно решать

Comment: `https?://[^/]+` - в зависимости от обработчика, слеши возможно нужно будет экранировать

Comment: Покажите требуемый ответ для показанного исходного значения, что ли...

Answer (score 1):

Ну например влоб:

```
/https?:\/\/(.*\.)*([^.\/]+\.[^.\/]+)\/.*/\2/gm
```

[fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/pv2NS9/1)

Comment: mail.radar.imgsmail.ru:443=54805
http://swa.mail.ru/cgi-bin/counters?=33857
rs.mail.ru:443=15562
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?=15207
http://suggest.yandex.ru/suggest-ya.cgi?=14152
waerr.radar.imgsmail.ru:443=14125
jim40.mail.ru:443=14070
http://counter.yadro.ru/hit?=13929
http://www.microsofttranslator.com/officetrans/httpquery.aspx=13112
http://t3.gstatic.com/images?=12942

Comment: Вот такой вывод в файл получается, не сократилось

Comment: @beartree https://regex101.com/r/pv2NS9/3 - всё сокращается.

Comment: mail.ru=204806
odnoklassniki.ru=127908
yandex.ru=112623
imgsmail.ru=110259
google.com=73897
gstatic.com=57670
taobaocdn.com=45717
google.ru=40136
adriver.ru=36889
vk.com=34608
Такой вариант(нужный) получается если использовать [a-z0-9-]+\\.(ru|com)

Comment: @beartree Я не понимаю, что Вы постите... ну почему МОИ ссылки на fiddle и скриншот нормально открываются, а Вы не можете так же? Из того, что Вы пишете - я НЕ МОГУ увидеть сути проблемы.

Comment: я не знаю почему оно работает на сайте, но не работает в моей программе

Comment: @beartree Посмотрите на fiddle, там список из 4 различных диалектов. Прикиньте количество возможных реализаций. И подумайте - а не имеет ли определённый смысл указать в вопросе требуемый диалект, используемый язык программирования, точное наименование и версию библиотеки работы с регулярными выражениями...

Answer (score 0):

Вот это вам подойдёт?

```
[a-z0-9-]+\.(ru|com)
```

Выбираю слово из символов a-z, 0-9 и символа дефиса длиной 1 или более, после которого идёт точка, после которого идёт `ru` или `com`.

Comment: и тут приходит пользователь с урлом http://mysite.org/test.com.ru/ и наслаждайтесь

Comment: @KoVadim и много таких бывает? Впрочем, сейчас подправлю

Comment: *и много таких бывает?* Да сейчас доменов первого уровня - как блох на собаке.

Comment: @Zhenyria Только добавьте еще один обратный слэш: [a-z0-9-]+\\.(ru|com)

Comment: @beartree И что получится? Заквоченный бэкслэш и неквоченная точка ака любой символ...

Comment: @Akina как это понять

Comment: @beartree В Вашем варианте `[a-z0-9-]+` - первый токен, ` \\ ` - второй, `.` - третий,  `(ru|com)`  - четвёртый.

Comment: @Akina это, конечно, печально, но с одним слэшэм просто не компилируется, а с вашим вариантом домен не сокращается

Comment: @beartree *а с вашим вариантом домен не сокращается* Давайте мой вариант обсуждать в комментариях к моему варианту, а? тем более что Ваши слова противоречат тому, что показывает online fiddle - у него почему-то всё сокращается... https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVlSi.png